# Handling SSO between two Django applications

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, single-sign-on, django-authentication

There is two Django-based application under a single platform with different sub-domain.
One of the applications is using an OpenSource project. Here databases are different between these applications and both respective user tables. We want to avoid making any major changes to this 2nd application(OSS one) to make sure there is maintainability.

The question is how can we have an SSO in a place where the user's signup on the 1st application(our main application), the users should be auto-logged in on the 2nd application too. The 1st application should ideally handle all sign-up/sign-in processes.
Both applications support SessionAuthentication.

Comment: Have you looked at [Keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/) ?

Comment: Hi @ArunT, No have not. Will look into it. 
It would be great if you can share some resources of implementation in Django specifically.